# C# Game of craps using dice roll method

Tags: c#, loops, random, methods

The code below is for a game of Craps. I am not sure if the logic of the code is correct. I want to test it, but when I run this code no output is given. It compiles and a blank screen is displayed with no output. I can't figure out why nothing is displayed. Also, any advice on the logic of the code would be appreciated. I am having difficulty with how to do the reroll process when 2, 3, 7, 11, or 12 are not rolled initially. Thanks

For those unfamiliar with the game: 2 dice are rolled and rolling a 7 or 11 is a win. 2, 3, or 12 is a loss. Any other number becomes the "point" and the player rerolls until the point or a 7 is rolled. Matching the point is a victory. This time a 7 is a loss.

```
class Craps
{
    const int dieSides = 6;

    int roll;
    //const int repeatGame = 1000;

    Random random = new Random();

    public void RollDice()
    {
        int die1 = 0;
        int die2 = 0;

        die1 = random.Next(6) + 1;

        die2 = random.Next(6) + 1;

        roll = die1 + die2;
        Console.WriteLine("The shooter roled: {0}", roll);
    }

    public void PlayCraps()
    {
        RollDice();
        int gameStatus = 0;
        int point = roll;
        int numRolls = 1;

        while (gameStatus < 1)
        {


            if (roll == 7 || roll == 11)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You won!");
                break;
            }
            else if (roll == 2 || roll == 3 || roll == 12)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You lost.");
                break;
            }
            else
            {

                RollDice();
                Console.WriteLine("The point is: {0}", point);

                while (point != roll || roll != 7)
                {
                    if (roll == point)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You won!");
                        numRolls++;
                        gameStatus++;
                    }

                    if (roll == 7)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You lost");
                        numRolls++;
                        gameStatus++;
                    }
                    RollDice();
                    numRolls++;

                }

            }
        }
    }



    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Craps NewGame = new Craps();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: how about calling NewGame.PlayCraps()

Comment: When you create a new game, nothing happen because you are not calling any craps' method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `Main` function, you're creating a `Craps` object, but never doing anything with it.

If you call `Craps.PlayCraps()`, that'll cause it to actually do something other than create an object and then wait for user input.

Answer (score 2):

I may be mistaken, but I believe in the main method, you should call the method, not just the class.
Example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Craps NewGame = new Craps();
    NewGame.PlayCraps();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the other suggestions that you in your `Main()` you call your `PlayCraps()` method on your new `NewGame` object like:

```
 Craps NewGame = New Craps();
 NewGame.PlayCraps();
```

You could *instead* call the `PlayCraps()` method in the `Craps` constructor:

```
class Craps
{
    const int dieSides = 6;

    int roll;
    //const int repeatGame = 1000;

    Random random = new Random();

    //start the game in the constructor:
    public Craps()
    {
       this.PlayCraps();
    }


    public void RollDice()
    {
        int die1 = 0;
        int die2 = 0;

        die1 = random.Next(6) + 1;

        die2 = random.Next(6) + 1;

        roll = die1 + die2;
        Console.WriteLine("The shooter roled: {0}", roll);
    }

    public void PlayCraps()
    {
        RollDice();
        int gameStatus = 0;
        int point = roll;
        int numRolls = 1;

        while (gameStatus < 1)
        {


            if (roll == 7 || roll == 11)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You won!");
                break;
            }
            else if (roll == 2 || roll == 3 || roll == 12)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You lost.");
                break;
            }
            else
            {

                RollDice();
                Console.WriteLine("The point is: {0}", point);

                while (point != roll || roll != 7)
                {
                    if (roll == point)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You won!");
                        numRolls++;
                        gameStatus++;
                    }

                    if (roll == 7)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You lost");
                        numRolls++;
                        gameStatus++;
                    }
                    RollDice();
                    numRolls++;

                }

            }
        }
    }



    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Craps NewGame = new Craps();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Now when you initialize your `NewGames` Craps object the `PlayCraps()` method will be called as part of that initialization and the game will start. I think the other way is a little more clear and it would allow you to set `Craps` properties (if they ever exist) before calling your `PlayCraps()` method, but I feel that the use of the constructor here is worth mentioning.